# How come when I update my iPhone SDK all the frameworks in my project turn red (not there)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks

I'm getting sick of this stuff happening. How come whenever I update my iPhone SDK all the frameworks in my project turn red as if there are not there anymore? Whats the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all your references to frameworks are "relative to base SDK"